# Stack Apps homepage truncates user names

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, stackapps, design

A picture says more than a thousand words:

[image]

These users aren't called "Bhargav Rac" and "Tunak", but [Bhargav Rao](https://stackapps.com/users/42239/bhargav-rao) and [Tunaki](https://stackapps.com/users/39463/tunaki).

This happens on both the ['apps'](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) and ['scripts'](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) tabs of [the Stack Apps homepage](https://stackapps.com/). Tested on Firefox and Safari on macOS, and Internet Explorer on Windows 8 (but there, the truncation is slightly less).

Comment: [Cross-site duplication, reported in MSE on Dec 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271970/312043)

Comment: @Arulkumar OIC, you're right. *tries to flag his question as cross-site duplicate, but fails to do so*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently the user name truncation issue has been fixed in the Stack Apps site, now it is looking good.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: User names]

Answer (score 4):

If you have TamperMonkey installed, this simple script should fix the problem:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SAHPA (Stack Apps Home Page Aligner)
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Aligns the user names on the StackApps Home Page
// @author       anonymous2
// @match        http://stackapps.com/
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @run-at       document-load
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("summary").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("summary")[i].childNodes[3].childNodes[5].childNodes[3].setAttribute('style', "float:right;margin-top:5px;margin-right:7px;line-height:18px;color:#999");
    }
})();
```

Not guaranteeing it's the most efficient way: still haven't found a way to reference those childNodes more directly, but it works.  :)